# Add metabox after title

Tags: php, wordpress

I have addded metabox in wordpress admin section. 
My Code :

```
   add_meta_box('cabcd', __( 'Page Settings', 'bg_textdomain' ), 'myplugin_meta_box_callback', 'page', 'side' );
```

Now I want it show after the title section.
How can I do that?

Comment: This may help you: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36600/how-can-i-put-a-custom-meta-box-above-the-editor-but-below-the-title-section-on

Comment: you should read the use of `add_meta_box()` before appling it in your codes http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box

Comment: Use
do_meta_boxes( get_current_screen(), 'test', $post );
# Remove the initial "advanced" meta boxes:
unset($wp_meta_boxes['post']['test']);

Comment: I got this code but unable to use it in proper way.

Comment: I got it from here link :http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36600/how-can-i-put-a-custom-meta-box-above-the-editor-but-below-the-title-section-on

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks to everyone who helped me.

Comment: Please select an answer, or add what worked for you, so that this question can be marked as resolved.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the `$priority` of the [add_meta_box()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box)

```
add_meta_box(
   'cabcd', 
   __( 'Page Settings', 
   'bg_textdomain' ), 
   'myplugin_meta_box_callback', 
   'page', 
   'side', 
   'high' // priority
);
```

Comment: Actually I need it to be shown just under the title section of the comment part.

Comment: @tri you have set the context `side` means your meta box will display on the side, there are two more cotext(normal, core) try with that.

Comment: Joges  have tried with both of that but it didnt work but I found some solutions on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36600/how-can-i-put-a-custom-meta-box-above-the-editor-but-below-the-title-section-on, but it still not working out for me.

Answer (score 1):

**this code is used to add meta box**

```
  <?php
         add_meta_box( $id, $title, $callback, $post_type, $context,
                $priority, $callback_args );
      ?>
```

**$priority**

> (string) (optional) The priority within the context where the boxes
>   should show ('high', 'core', 'default' or 'low') Default: 'default'

**you can try this** `(set the priority to high)`

```
 add_meta_box('cabcd', __( 'Page Settings', 'bg_textdomain' ), 'myplugin_meta_box_callback', 'page', 'side','high' );
```

more information [click](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box)

Comment: Actually I need it to be shown just under the title section of the comment part. this code is already tested from my side.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function custom_meta_box_markup()
{

}

function add_custom_meta_box()
{
    add_meta_box("demo-meta-box", "Custom Meta Box", "custom_meta_box_markup", "post", "after_title", "high", null);
}

add_action("add_meta_boxes", "add_custom_meta_box");

function edit_form_after_title() {
    // get globals vars
    global $post, $wp_meta_boxes;

    do_meta_boxes( get_current_screen(), 'after_title', $post );

    // unset 'ai_after_title' context from the post's meta boxes
    unset( $wp_meta_boxes['post']['after_title'] );
}
add_action( 'edit_form_after_title', 'edit_form_after_title' );
?>
```

Comment: I recon this is the correct way to do this but its not working for me. My metaboxes that I want to push up are added with the callback on register post type rather than add_meta_boxes hook though. Is that likely to be the cause of the issue?